# Flutter auto_route delegate and defaultRouteParser functions not exists

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I have generated routing using the [auth_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) (5.0.1) package in my project:

```
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
...
part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(page: AuthPage, initial: true),
    AutoRoute(page: TutorialPage),
    AutoRoute(page: LoginPage),
    AutoRoute(page: SmsVerificationPage),
  ],
)
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {}
```

The part-of file `app_router.gr.dart` generated successfully.

The problem is that the `AppRouter` class was not generated with the `delegate()` and `defaultRouteParser()` functions.

[image]

What is the problem? Anyone else is also facing the same issue?

### Update

It seems that everything works just fine when the AppRouter is generated **without a part-of file**.

According to the [official Setup](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#setup-and-usage), you can generate the file as part-of or not.

Apparently there is a sever difference between the two generated files:

[image]

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1216) to `auth_route` on Github. Feel free to follow and contribute!

Answer (score 3):

i had same problem (flutter version 3.3.4 and auto_route v 5.0.1).
my problem solved by importing auto_route to app_router.dart file (not generated file):

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
```

app_router.dart file:

```
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Screen,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
     ...
  ],
)
// extend the generated private router
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter{}
```

Comment: Hey @mhKarami thanks for replying. Not sure if I understand your answer correctly. The problem was that there are two methods to implement auto-routing, and the one that uses part-of generated file just does not work correctly. How does your approach solve this issue?

Comment: Feel free to check out the GitHub tread related this issue https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1216

Comment: hi @genericUser . my problem was same as your first image . the generated class show some errors . my problem solved by adding the `import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';` to the app_router.dart . in my case android studio intellisense did not suggest to import the missing reference . but i do not have any idea about your update .

Comment: this solve d my problem too, thanks :)